# Getting json() not an object, when I know it is

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 project where my login either returns an object with data or an object with an error message if no user exists.

Here is my code:

```
  userLogin(f){
    this.auth.login(f.value)
    .subscribe(res => { 
      console.log('Response: ' + res.json());
      //this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage') 
    }, err => {
      console.log('An error occured.')
    })
  }
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error that says res.json() is not a function.

Even though I can see in the console the following is returned when there is not user:

```
{"success":false,"msg":"Authentication failed. User not found."}
```

So why would I get the error:

```
ion-dev.js?v=3.0.1:156 ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to call this function yourself because **`HttpClient.get()`** applies res.json() automatically and returns **`Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`**.